# Does MySQL "lazy evaluate" when having queries inside IF (conditional) statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a SQL statement that has a conditional in it, and inside the conditional, there is a query. If the conditional is not true, will the query be evaluated anyways? or does MySQL 'lazily' evaluate subqueries as needed?

Sample Having Clause

```
HAVING
    IF(NOT isConfirmed, IF(
       IFNULL((SELECT SUM(net) as net from invoices where `to_id` = 5), 0)
       > 0
    , 1, 0) -- if its not confirmed, make sure total_paid total is greater than 0
, 1) -- otherwise dont care
```